# StyleCop SDK : How to get the project name of source document

Tags: stylecop

I am writing custom rules using StyleCop SDK. I need to get the name of visual studio project where the checked element resides. Is there any way to get this?

element.Document.SourceCode.Project does not give the project name.

Thanks,

Madhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.

string projectLocation = element.Document.SourceCode.Project.Location;

string projectName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(projectLocation).Trim();

Thanks,

Madhu